# Parse - Access other User's Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, parse-platform

I currently have a IOS app that allows users to create objects and save rows in the parse. I would like to allow them to see and edit other users data too. Currently they can only see their own with

```
    PFQuery *queryJournal = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
```

How would I allow them to touch other user's data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. But you can create another class (table) for the subset of data you want other users to access, meaning that a user's data is divided between two tables.